# Loading variable addresses into registers PowerPC inline Assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly, powerpc

I am trying to put together and example of coding inline assembly code in a 'C' program. I have not had any success. I am using GCC 4.9.0. As near as I can tell my syntax is correct. However the build blows up with the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccqC2wtq.s:48: Error: syntax error; found `(', expected `,'
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'all' failed
/tmp/ccqC2wtq.s:48: Error: junk at end of line: `(31)'
/tmp/ccqC2wtq.s:49: Error: syntax error; found `(', expected `,'
/tmp/ccqC2wtq.s:49: Error: junk at end of line: `(9)'
```

These are related to the input/output/clobbers lines in the code. Anyone have an idea where I went wrong?

```
  asm volatile("li 7, %0\n"           // load destination address
               "li 8, %1\n"           // load source address

               "li 9, 100\n"              // load count

               // save source address for return
               "mr   3,7\n"

               // prepare for loop
               "subi 8,8,1\n"
               "subi 9,9,1\n"

               // perform copy
               "1:\n"
               "lbzu 10,2(8)\n"

               "stbu 10,2(7)\n"
               "subi 9,9,1\n"              // Decrement the count
               "bne  1b\n"          // If zero, we've finished

               "blr\n"

               : // no outputs
               : "m" (array), "m" (stringArray)
               : "r7", "r8"
               );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this example is intended for, but I will say that inline asm is the most difficult way to learn and use asm.  In fact there are a [bunch](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) of reasons you should avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you are trying to do with the initial instructions:

```
li 7, %0
li 8, %1
```

Do you want to load the address of the variables into those registers? In general, this is not possible because the address is not representable in an immediate operand.  The easiest way out is to avoid using r7 and r8, and instead use %0 and %1 directly as the register names.  It seems that you want to use these registers as base addresses, so you should use the `b` constraint:

```
               : "b" (array), "b" (stringArray)
```

Then GCC will take care of the details of materializing the address in a suitable fashion.

You cannot return using `blr` from inline assembler because it's not possible to tear down the stack frame GCC created.  You also need to double-check the clobbers and make sure that you list all the things you clobber (including condition codes, memory, and overwritten input operands).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by declaring a pair of pointers and initializing them with the addresses of the arrays. I didn't realize that the addresses wouldn't be available directly. I've used inline assembly very sparsely in the past, usually just
to raise or lower interrupt masks, not to do anything that references variables. I just
had some folks who wanted an example. And the "blr" was leftover when I copied a 
snipet of a pure assembly routine to use as a starting point. Thanks for the responses.
The final code piece looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    char * stringArrayPtr;
    unsigned char * myArrayPtr;

    unsigned char myArray[100];

    stringArrayPtr = (char *)&stringArray;
    myArrayPtr     = myArray;

    asm volatile(
                 "lwz 7,%[myArrayPtr]\n"       // load destination address
                 "lwz 8, %[stringArrayPtr]\n"  // load source address

                 "li 9, 100\n"                 // load count
                 "mr 3,7\n"                    // save source address for return

                 "subi 8,8,1\n"                // prepare for loop
                 "subi 9,9,1\n"

                 "1:\n"                        // perform copy
                 "lbzu 10,1(8)\n"
                 "stbu 10,1(7)\n"
                 "subic. 9,9,1\n"              // Decrement the count
                 "bne  1b\n"                   // If zero, we've finished

                 // The outputs / inputs / clobbered list
                 // No output variables are specified here
                 // See GCC documentation on extended assembly for details.
                 : 
                 : [stringArrayPtr] "m" (stringArrayPtr), [myArrayPtr]"m"(myArrayPtr)
                 : "7","8","9","10"
                 );
}
```

Comment: Yuck, why would you force the compiler to store the pointers into locals for an `m` constraint instead of just asking for them in registers?  Use `"+r"` for your temporaries if you want to modify them.  And you dereference them without telling the compiler about it.  (Dummy input/output operand or `"memory"` clobber.  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](//stackoverflow.com/q/56432259))  Also, is that a byte load / byte store?  Double yuck, why copy only 1 byte at a time?  That's horrible vs. 128-bit SIMD or at least 4-byte integer regs.

Comment: All I wanted was the addresses of the arrays. After arguing with the assembler for a while and getting nothing but cryptic error messages that were no help, I decided that the easiest way was to use locals. As I said, this code was just a snipett from a pure assembly function. That was a optimized memcpy function that decided the fastest way to perform the copy, 32-bit, 16-bit or 8-bit. The addresses and count were passed into that routine. I prefer the pure assembly approach myself.

Comment: If you're introducing a store/reload of the pointer/length, that's a big obstacle to overcome for short copies.  There are several example on SO (including in the question I linked) of getting pointer inputs into an `asm` statement safely and efficiently.  Your code is not one of those example.  (Because of the lack of efficiency.)  If you need it in a specific register, use `int foo asm("r10")` or whatever.